# Missing Battery Health Warning Checkbox - Window 7 SP1 - Vaio Netbook

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, sony-vaio, battery-life

I am using Sony Vaio Netbook with retail Windows 7 SP1. 
I somehow felt (but not very sure) that battery might have drained quickly today.  I remember there is a setting something like ‘Warn if battery needs replacement’ in Power Options accessible from the Battery Icon in System Tray.

When I clicked on the battery icon, it does not show this option at all. I faintly remember seeing it as a check-box option earlier. Now I am unable to locate if there’s any other place in Control Panel -> Power Options where this can be enabled or could there be any registry setting etc. that can show that check-box. Most of the info on the internet is about enabling/disabling the system tray icons as such, nothing much about this specific setting.

Any inputs how to restore that option or may be any related clarification would be great.

[image: Power options]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Windows 7 has the ability to tell you when your battery is no longer holding a full charge. When your battery gets down to 40 percent of its original capacity (that is, it can only hold 40 percent or less of its designed capacity after it has been charged), you'll see a notification that says "Consider replacing your battery." Windows reports this information directly from the battery—you will only see this notification when the battery is reporting it's unable to hold more than 40% of a full charge.

This would explain why you can't find the option you're looking for. :)

You can read more on it [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/consider-replacing-your-battery)

Comment: Thanks @DrZoo for the info. This prompted me to check out with an earlier dead battery that I still have kept with me (for lack of e-waste disposal support) and that checkbox option (To hide the replacement warning)  re-appears now as it throws ‘battery needs replacement’ warning. I would have though the option should have been always configurable, but as you pointed out, it seems it is designed to be available only when battery starts to degrade.

Comment: @pat2015 I too thought it was always available. I never paid attention to it, until it appeared because I found it to be annoying

Answer (score 0):

#### Warn if battery needs replacement

There are more battery settings in "VAIO Control Center" > "Battery".

Perhaps you were thinking of these?

[image]

And:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Since I am using retail Windows 7, it seems I did not install many of the Sony provided optional utilities. So at the moment that Vaio Control panel specific option is not configurable for me.  However inputs & related info provided by user DrZoo turned out correct.